# Vertically align a div next to an image without tables or flexbox

Tags: css

I'm a newbie and I'm aware this question has been asked a lot, but I'm still groping to find a clear answer that I understand. I don't want to use tables or flexbox just plain CSS.

**Required:** 
I have an image and want to vertically center multiple lines of text to the right of the image.

**What i have tried:** 
I have put the text inside a div with display: inline-block. Then styled both image and div with vertical-align: middle.

**Question:** 
This seems to work, but why? Do I need to put the text inside a div? Can I write less code? The height of the image will change depending on the viewport width.

See this JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4LLruu7c/

```css
img {
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.list_text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(60% - 40px);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x200">
    <div class="list_text">Client name
      <br>Project title, desciption and blurb</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it works as both elements are inline elements and are vertically aligned to the middle.  You need the list_text div.  read more about vertical alignment when used with inline elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Thank you. To save a line of code I've tried removing vertical-align middle from both the image and div, and instead put it just on the ul. This didn't work, nor does it work if I put it on the li. Vertical align isn't inherited, so why do CSS Resets include it (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)?

Comment: Not sure about resets - I find they're pretty rubbish and full of bloat and usually for people who don't understand how to do css properly (which causes even more problems).  If you think of a sentence of words, those words are inline elements.  You can apply vertical align to them and it will change their position in line.  Now think about your image and div as two words in that sentence.  By applying your vertical align to them, it changes their position on the line.  By applying it to the parent - unless it is a table cell, then nothing will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align:

> **Values (for inline elements)**
>
> Most of the values vertically align the element relative to its **parent** element:
>
> **middle**
>
> *Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the x-height of the parent.*

This means you need to have the text div to make sure you have two inline elements and that they are vertically aligned in the middle of the line, relative to their parent.

As your image is the tallest thing on the line, it means the text div will be aligned to the middle of the line, which is in effect the middle of the image and that is why your code works